# xmlns declarations broken over multiple elements, "global" scope

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I want to break the xmlns declarations into multiple lines.  I've seen it in text books, but when I try to replicate it, [shell-tools][1] gives an error for the second example below:

/var/tmp/FOO758cqr:11: parser error : Premature end of data in tag book line 2

How do I change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- initially, the default namespace is "books" -->
<book xmlns="urn:loc.gov:books" xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">
  <title>Cheaper by the Dozen</title>
  <isbn:number>1568491379</isbn:number>
  <notes>
    <!-- make HTML the default namespace for some commentary -->
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          This is a <i>funny</i> book!
      </p>
  </notes>
</book>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <book xmlns="urn:loc.gov:books">
    <book xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">
      <title>Cheaper by the Dozen</title>
      <isbn:number>1568491379</isbn:number>
      <notes>
           <p>
              This is a <i>funny</i> book!
          </p>
      </notes>
    </book>
```

(above is from [scoping@w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#scoping))

I'd like to make the scope for both namespaces to be all of books, if that makes sense.

thanks,

Thufir

(reading [codenotes][3] pg 35)

Comment: err, on reading that, I see that a third xmlns is needed, for xhtml.  However, that doesn't materially change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
<book 
    xmlns="urn:loc.gov:books" 
    xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">
```

keeping the attributes within the single `<book>` node. Note that you can't have two root nodes, so two `<book>` nodes is not going to be acceptable in the above example.

Comment: Is it possible to break the two attributes (declarations?) to separate nodes?  I read something along the lines of "each namespace node has a parent but isn't the child of that parent," however, while I don't have it handy, codenotes does something like:                                                               <book xmlns="urn:loc.gov:books">                                           <book xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">   //formatting off

Comment: It's not possible to split that up. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: I was thinking of                                               <?xml version="1.0"?>
<library xmlns="urn:loc.gov:books">
  <book xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">
    <!--- omitted  -->
  </book>
</library>   or something like that, but I guess it's just a bad approach.  The broad scoped namespaces are put together into a single node (or element?).

Answer (score 2):

The second example is not well-formed XML (one of the `<book>` tags is not closed), that's why the error occurs.

What you might want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- initially, the default namespace is "books" -->
<book xmlns="urn:loc.gov:books" 
      xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">
  <title>Cheaper by the Dozen</title>
  <isbn:number>1568491379</isbn:number>
  <notes>
    <!-- make HTML the default namespace for some commentary -->
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          This is a <i>funny</i> book!
      </p>
  </notes>
</book>
```